# Math in section headings

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

In my thesis, I have math/Greek expressions in some of my section headings. 
I am given the error message:
`Token not allowed in PDF string`. I found `\textorpdfstring{}` from similar questions posted, and although it works in the final PDF, I would prefer to not have the error.

```
\subsection{\textorpdfstring{$E1$} transitions in and out of the   
    \textorpdfstring{$\kappa$} band}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `\texorpdfstring` takes two arguments, not just one. The command name stands for "TeX (commands) or PDF string". You should use, for example, `\textorpdfstring{$\kappa$}{k}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You'll get warnings in the log when using `hyperref`.

Comment: Interesting, my experiments indicate that it doesn't matter what the second argument is, so long as it contains no tokens.

Answer (score 11):

I think two separate issues need to be addressed:

- The command in question is called `\texorpdfstring`, not `\textorpdfstring`.
- The command takes two arguments -- the TeX string (which can contain math tokens) and the pdf string, which should not.

The following code runs fine. Incidentally, the `\boldmath` instruction at the start of the argument of `\section` is optional.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for '\texorpdfstring' command
\begin{document}
\section{\boldmath\texorpdfstring{$E1$}{E1} transitions 
   in and out of the \texorpdfstring{$\kappa$}{k} band}
\end{document}
```