# Error compiling code due to text in the title of a chapter that is encoded in math mode

Tags: tex-core

In the following code, I have a main file and a single chapter. The title of the chapter is

```
The Tale of Rabbit Reproduction: $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$
```

and I encoded it with

```
The Tale of Rabbit Reproduction: \texorpdfstring{$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$}{a[n] = a[n-1] + a[n-2]}
```

I am getting the following error message.

```
! Font U/bbold/m/n/24.88=bbold25 at 24.88pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

Is there a flaw in the code?

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside]{book}

% packages
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
%This package allows Chapter titles to be single spaced.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\setstretch{0.25}\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\setstretch{0.25}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\singlespacing\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\singlespacing\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}

% these make top, right, bottom margins confirming to the requirements

\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.0in,%
left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in,%
footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

% small stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}

\usepackage{footnote}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black}}

\usepackage{microtype}
% \usepackage{showkeys}
% uncomment this when editing cross-references
\numberwithin{equation}{section}




%------------------------------------------------




% doesn't count introduction when numbering theorems, etc.
\setcounter{chapter}{0}

% makes page numbers appear
\pagestyle{plain}


\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}



\begin{document}

% makes the page numbers roman numerals, doesn't count
% these pages in the table of contents
\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}

\vbox to 1truein{}

\centerline{Fairy Tales throughout History}



\vskip 200pt

\centerline{BY}
\vskip 10pt

\centerline{A Storyteller}
\vskip 10pt

\centerline{BA, Bard College}
\centerline{MA, Columbia University}

\vskip 215pt

\centerline{DISSERTATION}
\vskip 10pt

\centerline{Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements for}
\centerline{the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in English}
\centerline{in the Graduate School of}
\centerline{Columbia University}


\newpage


\thispagestyle{empty}

\vbox to 8.5truein{}

\centerline{\copyright\ Copyright by A Storyteller 2023}

\

\centerline{All Rights Reserved}

\newpage



\chapter*{Abstract}
\begin{doublespace}
Fairy tales' rich, imaginative stories for children~---~involving fantastical creatures and exotic places~---~offer far more than entertainment and happily-ever-after endings. They furnish children with a landscape for critical thinking skills and a context in which children can evaluate their own emotions and decision making.
\end{doublespace}


\newpage

\chapter*{Dedication}
\bigskip

\centerline{Dedicated to the Grimm Brothers and Hans Christian Anderson}

\newpage

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
I wish to thank Walt Disney for animating various fairy tales in full color.


\newpage

\tableofcontents

% Changes page numbers to regular numbers, resets the counter
\mainmatter

%This gives 10pt font with 20pt spacing, text from here should be double spaced
\fontsize{10}{20pt} \selectfont

% \include puts in the .tex file with the given name
% make sure that these files don't have any preamble material

\begin{doublespacing}

\include{March_30-Introduction}

%\include{March_30-Chapter_1}

%\include{March_29-Chapter_2}

\end{doublespacing}

% add a new chapter without a chapter # for the references
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Southey 1837]{Southey}Robert Southey, \emph{The Doctor},  Longman, Rees, Orme, Brown, Green and Longman, London, England, 1837, pages 318-326

\end{thebibliography}



\end{document}
```

Here is the only chapter in the file.

```
%
%
%
% Introduction
%
%

% make introduction a chapter without a #
\chapter*{Introduction (In case I decide to have a more descriptive name for the introduction, I want it to be single spaced or maybe half-line spaced)}

% and include it on the table of contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}


We will look at various fairy tales and myths in civilizations throughout history!

\newcommand\mymath{\(\sin(x) + 2ab - \frac{e^{2x}+1}{e^{2x}-1}\)}
\chapter{The Tale of Rabbit Reproduction: \texorpdfstring{$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$}{a[n] = a[n-1] + a[n-2]}}
```

Comment: Off topic:  don't load `amsfonts` separately.  It's already loaded by `amssymb'.

Comment: It seems something else which you don't show originates this.  There is no issue with ``\chapter{The Tale of Rabbit Reproduction: \texorpdfstring{$a_{n} = a_{n-1} +
  a_{n-2}$}{a[n] = a[n-1] + a[n-2]}}``.

Comment: The error your report appears to be related to the `bbold` font provided by `bbold` package support files.  You use `mathbbol` in that context.  Now I can't quite see where the `bbold25` comes from as the `Ubbold.fd` file does not contain a reference to it.

Comment: does the error keep showing if you comment out the line loading `mathbbol` package?

Comment: Can't reproduce, how did you install latex? Do you have the full tex-live installation?  Does using `\usepackage{bboldx}` instead of `\usepackage{mathbbol}` help?

Comment: @user691586  You are correct that removing the `mathbbol` package from the preamble allows the file to be compiled. I just have to put a `\boldmath` command before `$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$`.

Comment: @user691586 How would the `mathbbol` prevent the compilation of the recursive definition for the Fibonacci numbers in the title of the chapter? Also, the code would not compile if I had `\boldmath$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$\unboldmath` in the first argument of the `\texorpdfstring` command. I had to remove the `\unboldmath`. That is fine ... but why would that prevent the code from compiling?!

Comment: What does "I had to remove `\unboldmath`" mean. Why? When?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some Sherlock Holmes level enquiry in the [distant path](https://fr.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/tfyLhMeX/metric-tfm-file-not-found-comment-resoudre-ce-probleme) it looks as if in the past there was a guilty file `ubbold.fd` in `.../texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/` where I am using some kind of TeXLive base TeX installation.  From what I decipher there, this might explain `bbold25` showing in error message.

On my TeXLive 2023 I don't have one in this directory.  I have a `Ubbold.fd` in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbold`.  And this one should not cause problem.  The `bbold` package provides a `\mathbb`  command.

I advise you add `\listfiles` to your preamble and report what is shown in log after  `*File List*`. (mainly to know what kind of distribution you are using, is it up-to-date?)

Perhaps you have some such old `ubbold.fd` in some `texmf-local`?  or in a `texmf` in your `$HOME`?

It may be that adding a file named `ubbold.fd` like this

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bbold}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bbold}{m}{n}
   {  <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> gen * bbold
      <10> <10.95> bbold10
      <12> <14.4> bbold12
      <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> bbold17
   }{}
\endinput
```

in the directory of the project could fix this.
Perhaps. Maybe to be sure also save it as `Ubbold.fd`.  I am on a Mac, which is not case-sensitive.  Perhaps LaTeX NFSS normalizes anyhow by making things lowercased but I have not checked.

Comment: I don't have a complete TeXLive installation.  Which may explain I don't have a `jknapltx/ubbold.fd` file as involved in this. My best guess is that OP should remove `mathbbol` usage to start with.  The `amsfonts` package defines `\mathbb`.

Comment: I did add' \listfiles' to the preamble. You said to tell you what is written "in log after  *File List*."  I guess that you mean the log file that is written after compiling March_30-Main_file. I am using a personal computer. The files I get - besides the pdf file - are `Text`, `SYNCTEX`, `AUX`, `OUT`, `TOC` `BBL`, and `Performance Monitor`.

Comment: Somehow your TeX system removes the file with extension `.log` which is the crucial one for diagnostic.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I do remember that I would have to delete `.log` files from my directory. I haven't seen them in a long, long time.

Comment: OK. You did use the error message to determine that the `mathbbol` package in the preamble was preventing the code from compiling. I deleted it, made the appropriate modifications to my code, and got the display that I was intending. Thanks!!

Comment: @user143462 you are way too generous `;-)`... glad that you solved your issue in the end, hopefully it will not come back.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are getting is related to the `mathbbol` package you are using, which provides a font for extra math symbols. It seems that the font files required by the package are missing or not installed properly.

Make sure TeX Live or MiKTeX is up to date. Alternatively, you can try to use package `bbm` instead.

Comment: Almost surely, my `MikTeX` is not up-to-date. As user691586 had suggested, by removing the `mathbbol` package from the preamble, my LaTeX file `March_30-Main_file` compiled properly.